# Bézier curve tool: look different when open in browser

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve, corners, browser

I drew this using Bezier tool in Inkskape.

[image]

Saved as svg format. When oppened in browser I got the corner deformed (see the second picture)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a very short bezier-curve handle right on top of the node, which may be causing some visual glitches, possibly because of precision errors.

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking the round handle on top of the node to remove it, or select the segment extending to the left and click the 'Make selected segments lines' button in the toolbar.